# Java FX not working on linux-mint 18

Tags: javafx

I'm on linux mint 18 machine and got installed the openjdk 8 and the openjfx packages but when I try to execute a demo javafx project on the netbeans IDE what I get is this

`JNLP failed : Error: -includedt requires the java deployment toolkit, which is not included in this distribution`

`com.sun.javafx.tools.packager.PackagerException: Error: -includedt requires the java deployment toolkit, which is not included in this distribution`

(same java ugly error code)...

`impl.xml:2096: Error: Bundler "WebStart JNLP Bundler" (jnlp) failed to produce a bundle.`

Comment: I think the message says it all: "requires the java deployment toolkit, which is not included in this distribution". What is your question?

Comment: Can you try to create a example project http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ? Does this happen with the OracleJDK too?

Comment: I haven't acces to the OracleJDK, I can only use openjdk and openjfx and got that problem @FibreFoX.

Comment: @Axel I understand the message but I can't find nothing on the internet about how to install the java deployment toolkit, I don't know how to do that

Comment: Google showed me this result. Does it work for you? http://hongouru.blogspot.de/2015/09/solved-error-building-new-project-using.html

Comment: @Axel, many many thanks for the help, that works for me

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that's [a bug in openjdk / openjfx](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=269759), but [I've found a workaround](http://hongouru.blogspot.de/2015/09/solved-error-building-new-project-using.html):

In NetBeans, go to the Files tab and Locate the project.properties file in the nbproject folder inside the project folder. Open the file and change the following line

```
javafx.deploy.includeDT=true
```

to this:

```
javafx.deploy.includeDT=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this and solved the problem for me (Linux Mint 18) :

> Currently in Debian and Ubuntu (probably others) JavaFX is a separate package >from the OpenJDK (openjdk-8-jdk) and so needs to be installed:
>
> `sudo apt-get install libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-java-doc`